# NoMethodError: undefined method 'index' when calling deliver on rails 3.1 mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I have set up a staging instance of a rails 3.1 application on Heroku and everything seems to work fine except I'm getting a strange error when I try to send emails. I am using the sendgrid starter addon for email delivery. The full error is below:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `index' for #<Mail::Message:0x000000048daf28>
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:1289:in `method_missing'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/encodings.rb:117:in `value_decode'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/encodings.rb:101:in `decode_encode'
    /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:74:in `do_decode'
```

if I just generate the message object without calling deliver on it and inspect it everything seems fine. I am not seeing this error on my production app. Can you tell me what this error means and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the same error on my local machine using Rails 3.0.11. It happened after I passed some object instead of a string to the `mail` `:to` attribute. So be sure that the `:to` attribute is a string!

```
mail(to: object.to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

A new version of Mail, Mail 2.4.0, was released this weekend. I would recommend upgrading to this latest version and seeing if that has fixed your issue.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Can you recommend the best way to do this given that the rails ActionMailer dependency is currently set to 2.3.0? I see that a commit was just made to Rails edge to upgrade to 2.4.0 but I cannot use edge because of other gem dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This error was the result of using Class instead of Module when defining a mail helper I'd created.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened because I was setting custom headers to an integer value. Using to_s on these values resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  However, the error I received was:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass)
```

My problem was I had:

```
mail(to: emails,....)
```

And my variable "emails" was actually an array, instead of being one single string of emails.